# Parse C char array sent via web server into (JSON or JavaScript) variables

Tags: c, arrays, json, parsing, webserver

**Desired outcome:** Send a struct of GPS data from C using a web server and have the data ( lat, long, etc.) display on a web page.

**Using:** Linux, libwebsockets (LWS) library for web server. C code is implemented as a standalone plugin in the LWSWS (web server) app.

**Current understanding/work on project:** Casting struct from plugin to a char array and trying to parse the array (using JSON) into the individual members of the original struct. Then display each variable on a web page.

I am new to Linux, LWS, HTML, JavaScript, and JSON. I can use JSON or Javascript to work with the variables, whichever makes more sense. I am not completely sure of my plan on either side (C/JS) of this part of the project.

**What is the best way to transfer this information and convert for use on the web page?**

Here is my struct:

```
struct per_session_data__gps_rcvr {
    struct time_struct{
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;

        int hour;
        int minute;
        double second;
    }time;

    double latitude;
    char lat_indicator;

    double longitude;
    char lon_indicator;

    double heading;

    int quality;
    int satellites;
};
```

Sending struct out, cast to a char pointer:

```
    // Write GPS data to GUI
    n = lws_snprintf( (char *)p, sizeof(buf) - LWS_PRE, "%s", (char *)pss );
    m = lws_write(wsi, p, n, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
    if (m < n) {
        lwsl_err("ERROR %d writing to di socket\n", n);
        return -1;
    }
    break;
```

The test code I am modifying appears to receive data in a variable called "msg". I am assuming I need to parse the data sent in the char array into chunks that correspond to the members of the original struct. Then I can display each piece of GPS data on the web page.

```
var socket_gps;

if (use_lws_meta)
    socket_gps = lws_meta.new_ws("", "gps-rcvr-protocol");
else
    socket_gps = new_ws(get_appropriate_ws_url(""), "gps-rcvr-protocol");

try {
    socket_gps.onopen = function() {
        document.getElementById("wsdi_statustd").style.backgroundColor = "#40ff40";
        document.getElementById("wsdi_status").innerHTML =
            " <b>websocket connection opened</b><br>" +
            san(socket_gps.extensions);
    } 

    socket_gps.onmessage =function got_packet(msg) {
        document.getElementById(" **VARIABLE GOES HERE** ").textContent = msg.data + "\n";
    } 

    socket_gps.onclose = function(){
        document.getElementById("wsdi_statustd").style.backgroundColor = "#ff4040";
        document.getElementById("wsdi_status").textContent = " websocket connection CLOSED ";
    }
} 
catch(exception) {
    alert('<p>Error' + exception);  
}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to send the data out from C, and/or if I have correctly configured the data. In my research, it was mentioned that data could be sent as binary, but sending plain text messages and using JSON seemed like a better plan.

It looks like JSON can "stringify" info, but only if it's typed in or in JavaScript format already? I'm not sure. I have not seen any way to parse out a char array, a set number of characters at a time, and save those segments as variables on the HTML side. That is what I was hoping for.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
n = snprintf( (char *)p, sizeof(buf), "{\"NameofParam1\":\"%d\",\"NameofParam2\":\"%d\"}", param1, param2 );
```

That gives you your whole JSON string in one go (stored in buffer). Just use the appropriate flag (%s, %X, %c, %f, etc.) to capture your parameter.